# How do you "fix" decimal points when converting to DMS?

Tags: ti-basic

In TI-Basic, there's a `Fix` function to limit the number of displayed decimal places. For example, `Fix 2` would display only 2 decimal digits. However, when I try to convert a number to Degree-Minute-Second notation, I sometimes get more than the number of "fixed" decimal digits. For example,

```
1.12345678901
Float
Disp Ans►DMS
Fix 2
Disp Ans►DMS
Float
Disp Ans
Fix 2
Disp Ans
```

displays

```
1°7'24.444"
1°7'24.444"
1.123456789
1.12
```

The normal decimals act as expected. However, I would expect the second line to display `1°7'24.44`. Is this possible? Or would I have to somehow convert it to a string and prune afterwards? (Keep in mind that I want to shorten the decimal because of the display constraints; I want to display text next to it without overlap).

extra info: TI-84+ Silver Ed'n, OS version 2.55 w/MathPrint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`►DMS` will display 0 to 3 digits after the decimal point, solely depending on the length of the decimal.  The `Fix` command, set programmatically or through `MODE` does not affect this.

Storing a number formatted in DMS in a variable will undo the DMS formatting, and it cannot be stored in a string.

My suggestion would be isolating the degrees, minutes, and seconds in separate variables and working with them from there.  In this way, they would also all be affected by the `Fix` command.

Comment: Do you mean for me to do the math myself and store the results to separate vars (eg. D,M,S)? Because in that case, displaying it would be an issue.

Comment: A complicated workaround, to be sure.  But yes, and then display D° M' S"